# What are optimal approaches for getting my HTML import to work on more than just Chrome?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, mobile-website, opentok, html-imports

I have a fully baked app in Bubble.is that involves patients having appointments with clinicians via video chat.  If at all possible, I would like to avoid having to build out a client-server setup just for the video chat piece.  This is why OpenTok's embeds stood out for me.  Whatever Bubble.is adds to the header, it breaks OpenTok's embed file when I directly embed it.  So instead, I serve up the OpenTok embed from an html file on another domain I own.  So now I have the app (app.foo.bar) and the OpenTok embed (www.foo.bar/opentok.html), and am trying to use an HTML import.

Embedded code (header):

```
<script src="https://polygit.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://foo.bar/scripts/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="https://foo.bar/video/index.php/embed-2">
```

Embedded code (body):

```
<script> window.addEventListener('HTMLImportsLoaded', function() {
var link = document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]');
var content = link.import;

 //Grab DOM from embedded OpenTok.
var el = document.querySelector('#otEmbedContainer');

document.body.appendChild(el.cloneNode(true));});</script>
```

As expected, this works beautifully on Chrome desktop, but nowhere else.  What are some of the optimal approaches I can take to modify this existing code such that I can run this on (at a minimum) mobile web?

Comment: choose between webcomponents-loader and webcomponents-lite but don't use both at the same time. i'd recommend the latter

Answer (score 1):

You can use an iframe in Bubble.io. You do not need to use an HTML import. When you create the OpenTok embed, set the Website URL for the embed to `https://your-app-name.bubbleapps.is` (replace `your-app-name` with the name of your Bubble.is app). Then in Bubble.is, add an HTML element to your app and paste the OpenTok embed iframe code in as the code for the element. Also, you need to add this attribute to the iframe: `allow="microphone; camera"`

So, the code you paste into the Bubble.is HTML element looks like this:

```
<iframe src="https://tokbox.com/embed/embed/ot-embed.js?embedId=your-embed-id-xxxxx&room=DEFAULT_ROOM&iframe=true" 
width=800 height=640 allow="microphone; camera" >
</iframe>
```

Click the Preview button in the Bubble.is editor, and the OpenTok embed works.

Comment: Safari does not let iFrames access microphone or camera, and iOS does not allow same for any browser.  Our app is mobile first, so cross device video chat support for phones is make or break.